# Getting SQL syntax error in MySQL query issue

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT id, `name`, active, username, `function`, email ,
( IF active = '1' THEN SET active = 'Active') AS active ELSEIF  active = '0' SET active = 'Inactive' ELSEIF active IS NULL SET active = '-') AS active

FROM users ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I want to check if active is 1 then set active to 'Active' else if ...... What am I doing wrong ?

**UPDATE ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
 server version for the right syntax to use near 'active == '1' THEN SET active = 
'Active') as active ELSEIF  active == '0' SET ac' at line 2
```

Comment: Show the error meassage please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` condition does not have such a syntax. You can use a `case`

```
SELECT id, `name`, active, username, `function`, email,
       case when active = '1' then 'Active'
            when active = '0' then 'Inactive'
            when active is null then '-'
       end AS active_value
FROM users 
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

And you can't have 2 columns with the same name. I named the case `active_value`

Comment: thx man , so there is no way to do this with if else ? just for my curiosity

Comment: `if/else` is for 2 condtions. You have 3 here. And `if` syntax is: `if(condition, true_value, false_value)`